# Is my topojson file structured properly in order to render a map on folium?

Tags: topojson, folium

I've downloaded the us-counties shapefile from the US census bureau and converted it into topojson file using mapshaper.com. Unfortunately, I have to parse through the topojson quite a bit to get the FIPS county code. I'm using Folium to render the map but keep getting an error.

I've taken my dataframe and made it into a series of FIPS_codes and $amounts. Using the style_function, I call the FIPS_codes from the topojson file and compare that value to the series to render a map of us-counties.

```
import branca
colorscale = branca.colormap.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(0, 50e3)
def style_function(feature):
    county_dict = cms_2017_grouped_series.get(
features['objects']['tl_2017_us_county']['geometries']['properties']['GEOID'], None)
    return {
        'fillOpacity': 0.5,
        'weight': 0,
        'fillColor': '#black' if employed is None else colorscale(employed)
    }
```

The error I'm getting is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

The rest of code needed to render the map is below

```
m = folium.Map(
    location=[48, -102],
    tiles='cartodbpositron',
    zoom_start=3
)

folium.TopoJson(
    json.load(open(county_geo)),
    'objects.tl_2017_us_county.geometries.properties.GEOID',
    style_function=style_function
).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Assuming your error is happening in your style function.  `cms_2017_grouped_series` is a list that you're treating like a dict when you use .get()

Comment: even after I change the ```cms_2017_grouped_series``` into a dictionary, I still get the same error. I believe its the way the topojson file is structured.

Comment: Reviewing your question.  Looks like your trying to bind data in a dataframe to a map.  If thats true, I think folium's choropleth is a better fit.  Is there a particular reason you're using TopoJson?

Comment: I'm using TopoJson because my data frame is very large and if I use GeoJson my map crashes and because I'd like to use the ```style_functions```.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll post something shortly

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps to create the topojson and good news, it checks out.  Just need to change up a couple of things with your code

I created some mock user data first. I'm using geopandas and the topjson file to make it easy on myself, but you would just use your pandas dataframe that contains county and employment numbers

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file('tl_2017_us_county.json')

gdf['employed'] = np.random.randint(low=1, high=100000, size= len(gdf))
```

Create a Series using your dataframe. This will be used in the style func to "bind" your data to the map

```
cms_2017_grouped_series = gdf.set_index('GEOID')['employed']
print(cms_2017_grouped_series.head())
GEOID
31039    54221
53069    68374
35011     8477
31109     2278
31129    40247
Name: employed, dtype: int64
```

This is pretty close to your style function.  I've just changed the line with the `.get()` to use the corrected dict keys of `feature`.  Oh and I'm using the return value(`employed`) in the fillColor below

```
import branca
colorscale = branca.colormap.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(0, 50e3)

def style_function(feature):

    employed = cms_2017_grouped_series.get(feature['properties']['GEOID'], None)

    return {
        'fillOpacity': 0.5,
        'weight': 0,
        'fillColor': '#black' if employed is None else colorscale(employed)
    }
```

Slight mod of the `object_path` is next.  I'm also saving the map and then opening it in Chrome since it wouldn't render in my notebook due to the size

```
m = folium.Map(
    location=[48, -102],
    tiles='cartodbpositron',
    zoom_start=3
)
folium.TopoJson(open('tl_2017_us_county.json'), 'objects.tl_2017_us_county', 
                style_function=style_function).add_to(m)
m.save('map.html')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I believe it's the way my topojson file is structured.

Comment: @RunningCoyote I respectfully disagree.  The error you posted points toward `cms_2017_grouped_series.get()` and I posted a workable solution using that file.  Best of luck